# When I verify a signed document with gpg, how does it know what public key to use?

Tags: gnupg, signature

When I sign a document, I can select the secret key to use e.g. like this:

```
gpg --default-key=BF8C1203 --clearsign message.txt
```

When I verify a document, I do not see this option, I can just do:

```
gpg --verify message.txt.asc
```

How does GPG know what public key to use for the verification? Is there a way to tell it to use a different public key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `gpg` checks the signature against all the public keys you have.

If you have two private keys, you should also have the corresponding public keys. So, `gpg` will look through all the public keys you have, including your friend's keys, and figure out who signed the file.

If the file is signed by me and you don't have my public key, then `gpg` can't verify my signature, until you download my public key from a public key repository like https://pgp.mit.edu/

More detailed explanation below is from https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-signing-email-with-gpg-how-does-verification-by-the-receiver-work

> There is a unique association between public and private key. That is,
>   **if the sender uses a certain private key to sign a message and you verify the signature using the corresponding public, then the
>   signature verification will succeed only if the message has not been
>   altered.**
>
> The verification procedure and nature of the association between
>   public and private varies with the cryptosystem you are considering
>   (RSA, DSA, etc.), but the statement above holds true for any
>   asymmetric scheme.
>
> What really matters is that **the sender is the only one that can
>   produce a valid signature because he/she is the only one who knows the
>   private, but anyone knows the public, so anyone can verify the
>   signature.**
>
> Upon signing, GPG adds a token to the text message which can be used
>   to verify that the message has not been altered in transit: that's the
>   signature. You don't need GPG to read the message because the text
>   itself is not encrypted, there is only an extra token, which could be
>   either a radix64-encoded blob at the end of the message or a text
>   attachment with a similar structure.
>
> GPG does not directly sign the message, it signs a cryptographic hash
>   (SHA-1 or SHA-2 usually) of it. What happens upon verification is that
>   the signature is verified using the public key of the sender to make
>   sure the received hash was actually originated by the sender. If the
>   hash calculated by the sender is considered authentic, it is compared
>   with the hash calculated by the recipient. If both phases succeed,
>   then the message is correctly signed.

Hope this helps